# Outlook as a lightweight IMAP client

Tags: outlook, imap

Is it possible to configure Outlook (Version 1812, part of Office 365) as an IMAP client without downloading *everything* in Drafts, Sent, Spam, Trash?

Starting from a clean profile, I add a user, and the Send/Receive crawls for 25 minutes (or more; still not done yet), downloading 250MB into the .pst file.

I check the IMAP folders, and the only subscribed folders are the ones mentioned above (aka "special folders" in Outlook-speak). Can't unsubscribe to them.

I'm thinking of migrating my users to Mailbird, but a few are quite attached to Outlook. Out of the box Mailbird seems to do just to the right thing.

Comment: Are you wanting to switch because it's what you want or because it's what your users want?

Comment: I only mention alternatives to make the point that it's possible to have IMAP be lightweight.  If it was up to me I'd just switch application.  My users though are resistant to change.

Comment: Correction, it's the .ost file.

Comment: and it's 815MB after completing send/receive.

Comment: There should be an option in Outlook to download only the email headers. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

As your description, you need to enable and configure IMAP4 client connectivity in Exchange. The brief steps are as below:

1.Start the IMAP4 services, and configure the services to start automatically.

2.Configure the IMAP4 settings for external clients.

3.Restart the IMAP4 services to save the changes.

4.Configure the authenticated SMTP settings for internal and external clients.

For more information, you can see [Enable and configure IMAP4 on an Exchange server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-imap4?view=exchserver-2016) What's more, You can also selete Outlook online mode, more details, see the link below,  or narrrow down offline periodm like 1 month.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5d00a0df-1dda-4fcb-9c4f-e85bde567410/how-to-set-outlook-working-online?forum=outlook

[image]